# about super.onBackPressed() animate reveal

Tags: android, android-animation, uiviewanimationtransition

### Android about super.onBackPressed() animate reveal

- In the android login program, click the bottom right registration button to show the opening animation of a registration page,and then an animation appears on the bottom left to return to the login page button.OK, all of this is fine.
- I would have clicked the left login button at the bottom of the page, and there would be an animation to close the registration page, and an animation displayed on the right side of the bottom would show the login page button.But there are problems with the implementation.After closing the animation, the button animation showing the login page cannot be displayed.I think because `RegisterActivity. Super. OnBackPressed ()`  I don't know what to do.Thanks

> Source code:

```
 /**
 * Close the page animation
 */
public void animateRevealClose() {
    int centerX = (mCardViewRegister.getWidth()) / 2;
    int centerY = (mToSignUpCardView.getTop() + mToSignUpCardView.getBottom()) / 2;
    int startRadius = mCardViewRegister.getHeight();
    int endRadius = mToSignUpCardView.getWidth() / 2;
    Animator mAnimator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
            mCardViewRegister,
            centerX,
            centerY,
            startRadius,
            endRadius);
    mAnimator.setDuration(500);
    mAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    mAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            BottomFastSignUp(); //The bottom button displays the animation.
            mCardViewRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            RegisterActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationStart(animation);
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();}
```

method `onBackPressed()`

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    animateRevealClose();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `RegisterActivity.super.onBackPressed();` in animation end? And pls add the code where you call this method

Comment: Because after clicking the bottom to the login button to `animateanimateRevealClose()`,Realize the `animationBottomFastSignUp()` . Finally `super.onBackPressed()` has a transition animation back to the login page but the `BottomFastSignUp()` and `super.onBackPressed()` seem to be in conflict.

Comment: `BottomFastSignUp` method runs another animation, right? How about `mCardViewRegister` view, I see you hide it but what is the purpose, what content does it have? Will hiding the `mCardViewRegister` also hide the animation inside `BottomFastSignUp`?. Many things in the code you posted need to be clarified so post everything you can that related to the main problem can help to investigate the problem faster

Comment: The `BottomFastSignUp ()` is an animation that runs.`AnimateRevealClose ()` is an animation that closes the registration page.So hide the `mCardViewRegister` registration page at the end of the animation.Run the animation showing the registration button, and finally back to the login page.

Comment: For your better analysis, see this [demo](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/compact-login) I set the bottom registration button to the Shared element instead of the Fab button.`BottomFastSignIn()` is the display animation of the position of the bottom button. After the animation is closed, the Shared element button will return to the lower right corner.

Comment: I update what I understand in my answer, check it out

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand from our discussion:

**1/**

You start the close animation when back button pressed, but then call `super.onBackPressed()` immediately which make the activity finish and any animation setting up is useless.

So remove `super.onBackPressed();` is the first fix.

**2/**

In close animation's end event, you call `BottomFastSignUp` which is another animation but again call `RegisterActivity.super.onBackPressed();`. This makes the activity finish and the animation is useless again.

So to fix this, don't finish the activity before all the animations are finished.

There are 2 options to fix:

- Listen to the `BottomFastSignUp` animation end and call `finish` there.
- Move `BottomFastSignUp` to `LoginActivity`. You can finish the `RegisterActivity`, override `onActivityReenter` in `LoginActivity` and do the `BottomFastSignUp` there instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, which seems it's a promising solution.Wish you a happy life

Comment: Glad I can help